# Selecting rows with similar index names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a Pandas DataFrame of the following form:

```
     a  b  c
a_1  1  4  2
a_2  3  3  5
a_3  4  7  2
b_1  2  9  8
b_2  7  2  6
b_3  5  4  1
c_1  3  1  3
c_2  8  6  6
c_3  9  3  7
```

Is there a way I could select only rows that have similar names? In the case of the DataFrame above that would mean selecting only the rows that start with a, or the rows that start with b, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @Akavall setup code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = my_data, index=['a_1', 'a_2', 'b_1', 'b_2'], columns=['a', 'b'])

In [1]: my_data = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)

In [2]: my_data[0,0] = 4

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data = my_data, index=['a_1', 'a_2', 'b_1', 'b_2'], columns=['a', 'b'])

In [5]: df.filter(regex='a',axis=0)
Out[5]: 
     a  b
a_1  4  1
a_2  2  3

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Note that in general this is better posed as a multi-index

```
In [6]: df.index = MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],[1,2]])

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
     a  b
a 1  4  1
  2  2  3
b 1  4  5
  2  6  7

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [8]: df.loc['a']
Out[8]: 
   a  b
1  4  1
2  2  3

[2 rows x 2 columns]

In [9]: df.loc[['a']]
Out[9]: 
     a  b
a 1  4  1
  2  2  3

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine for the given problem, with the very important comment about the multi-index, however I will not delete my post since there is some additional information in there

Comment: Multiple answers are good! Their are reasons to have code just like th e OP's so your is valid as well.

Comment: Using multiple indexing is a better idea, sadly it's not up to me in this case to change the structure of the DataFrame. Do you think there would be a significant difference in performance between both approaches when dealing with very big DataFrames?

Comment: well, you can simply try it. you can just copy the frame and set the index; do what you need and convert back (in 0.14 set_index will do this for you). just try both ways. it depends on what you are going so YMMV

Comment: Very nice answer, but when I try `df.filter(regex='a',axis=0)`, I get: TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'. I am using 'pandas 0.12.0', so I am guessing that's my problem. Are you using later version? `pandas 0.13.1'?

Comment: yep I think I added axis in 0.13

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a build-in `pandas` way to do it, but here is one way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)
my_data[0,0] = 4

df = pd.DataFrame(data = my_data, index=['a_1', 'a_2', 'b_1', 'b_2'], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

Result:

```
>>> df
     a  b
a_1  4  1
a_2  2  3
b_1  4  5
b_2  6  7
>>> start_with_a = [ind for ind, ele in enumerate(df.index) if ele[0] == 'a']
>>> start_with_a
[0, 1]
>>> df.loc[start_with_a]
     a  b
a_1  4  1
a_2  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

in general you can access the row index and the columns with the .index and .columns attributes.

so you can easily get the rows that start with *a* programmatically

```
needed_rows = [row for row in df.index if row.startswith('a')]
```

then you can use these rows like this

```
df.loc[needed_rows]
```